# didSelect only firing once for same pin

Tags: swift, mkmapview

I have a map with many pins placed. I also have the following code

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView){
    print("Test")
}
```

When I tap the pin, the function is entered correctly and "Test" is printed to the console. The problem I am facing is that, following taps of the same pin cause no execution of the above code.

To get the code to execute again, I have to tap another pin, then tap the original pin again.

How do I get the above function to fire, no matter how many times I tap the pin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method is called when the pin is *selected*, not when it is tapped - though tapping it for the first time causes selection, which will remain until another pin is tapped, or the selection is cleared programmatically.

You need to deselect it before the method will be called again, using `mapView.deselectAnnotation`, which you could do within the `didSelect`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clearout the selected annotations to select it again.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
       let selectedAnnotations = mapView.selectedAnnotations
        for annotation in selectedAnnotations {
            mapView.deselectAnnotation(annotation, animated: false)
        }
  }
```